# How to config socks proxy in Java NIO

Tags: java, classloader, nio

I'm developing a tool which includes forcing all network traffic of application to go across a socks proxy in Java. For old Socket API, I can just set system properties "-DsocksProxyHost=my-host -DsocksProxyPort=my-port", but it doesn't work with NIO.

I tried a solution:

I wrote an NIO SocketChannel, called "ProxySocketChannel" which extends SocketChannel. It contains socks connection and other socks proxy logic. But when I run it, I got an "IllegalSelectorException" in this line of code in "SelectorImpl.register":

```
if (!(ch instanceof SelChImpl))
        throw new IllegalSelectorException();
```

sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl is package visible so I can't access it. I tried a tricky solution: I put my "ProxySocketChannel" in package "sun.nio.ch". The compilation passed, but I got an error when running:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.nio.ch.ProxySocketChannel cannot access its superinterface sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl
```

I don't know why the class sun.nio.ch.ProxySocketChannel with package sun.nio.ch still can not access sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl. I think there is some protection for JDK built-in classes. Is there a way to access it?

My JDK Version is 1.6.0_65.

Otherwise, is there a way to setup socks proxy for NIO without change existing code?

Comment: `IllegalAccessError` has to do with the fact that all classes in the same package must be loaded by the same `ClassLoader`. Unfortunately, library classes are loaded via the bootstrap CL, while the application classes are loaded via the system CL. So you cannot access the parent as it is in a different package.

Comment: Thanks! 

I tried to load my class in BootstrapClassLoader by 
writting a Java agent put a line and it works: 
      
`inst.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(new JarFile(mockFile))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is seriously difficult. I wrote an `SSLSocketChannel` class some years ago and I ended up having to write my own `SSLSelectorProvider`, `SSLSelector`, and `SSLSelectionKey` classes as well. You can't just add a `SocketChannel`-derived class into the existing infrastructure: it is specifically designed to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

EJP is right, this is hard stuff. You can use a *dirty trick* to register the OPs to the original `SocketChannel` and then swap the channel on-the-fly to your own implementation once the OPs are triggered. But the correct approach is to write your own `SelectorProvider`, `Selector` and `SelectionKey` which will make you seriously consider using *stunnel* for SSL if you can.