# How do I use Java NIO sockets via a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: nio

Are any libraries or code available using SocketChannel?

[This blog post](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/08/java-nio-and-overengineering.html) suggests that one might have to implement SOCKS, a position which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487363/how-to-config-socks-proxy-in-java-nio) supports. I havn't discovered any code yet.

Thanks